# Generate HeaderCode From GeneratedCode in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sup

We have gone through the sybase online tutuorial for SUP2.0. In that

Sybase Unwired Platform 2.0 > Developer Guide for iOS > Development Task Flows > Developing Applications in the Xcode IDE>Generating HeaderDoc from GeneratedCode.

**Generating HeaderDoc from Generated Code**

***Once you have generated Objective-C code for your mobile business objects, you can generate
HeaderDoc (HTML reference information) on the Mac from the generated code. HeaderDoc
provides reference information for the MBOs you have designed. The HeaderDoc will help
you to programmatically bind your device application to the generated code.

1. Navigate to the directory containing the generated code that was copied over from the
   Eclipse environment.
2. Run:

> headerdoc2html –o GeneratedDocDir GeneratedCodeDir
>   gatherheaderdoc GeneratedDocDir

You can open the file OutputDir/masterTOC.html in a Web browser to see the
interlinked sets of documentation.***

we have followed the step mentioned in that link. and four files are generating  in the generated code folder but all the files is having zero bytes size. Can you help by saying wher the error have occured.

we have set the path as

desktop/mac_ios/importing_lib_code through the terminal and give the scripts mentioned in the tutorial.

importing_lib_code is having subfolders src which contains two subfolders common and folder holding .m files.

adn second one is includes folder with two subfolder containing the .h files of corresponding file.